# BleachBit reduces space for no reason

Tags: files, disk, disk-usage, bleachbit

I ran the bleachbit program and ran the 'Free Disk Space'. I noticed that is started to fill up my hard Disk COMPLETELY (almost). I have currently lost 20 GB of space. I have 2 folders in my home directory.[image]

When I `ls -l` or `ls` inside either of the directories, It kind of freezes.

The funny thing is that it says the directory is 500 MB. When I do Shift + Del, It ran for about 10 hours and still said - ' Preparing to delete ~9,00,000 files '
I cannot `rm -f` anything. can somebody please help

Thanks,

Rochan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BleachBit 1.2 fixes several problems with wiping free disk space](http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/news/bleachbit-12) including a way to prevent this, so I assume you are using an older version.

Now that you have this problem you just have to let `rm -rf` run.  Linux file systems can take a very long time to delete many files, even if they are empty.

It may look like nothing is happening for a while, but you can verify the number of inodes is increasing with this command: `watch df -i`

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine that you have "Wipe free space" set. This will overwrite all the free space on the hard drive to prevent recovery of previous files, and then delete what it has created

Comment: Is there any way to delete it. I have tried almost everything.

Comment: Try deleting it as root

Comment: sudo rm -rf ~/Junk

Comment: thanks a lot David, I will surely try and keep you posted. Thanks for taking time to solve this issue once again.